# Created a custom Worker class and called it by a PeriodicWorkRequest in MainActivity, but for some reason the constructor shows that it's not used

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner and as the title says, I am creating a custom Worker class and calling it a `PeriodicWorkRequest` in the MainActivity's code. I have made a constructor and the `onWork()` method as the tutorials I found online said, but the code doesn't seem to work and my only hint for why is that Android Studio says "no usage" on top of the constructor.
Here's the code of the custom Worker class:

```
public class BackgroundService extends Worker {
    private int i = 0;
    public BackgroundService(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        //my code
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        try {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Number: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i++;
            return Result.success();
        } catch(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return Result.failure();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the code of the MainActivity inside the `onCreate()`:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest workRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BackgroundService.class, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
                WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(workRequest);
```

My goal is simply to test how the `PeriodicWorkRequest` works by incrementing the number every 10 seconds and showing it to the user on a Toast, but no Toast ever shows up and there doesn't seem to be a sign that the Worker is running. I suspect it has something to do with the constructor not being used, and thus, the class never receives the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

The minumum interval must be at least 15 minutes as stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/persistent/getting-started/define-work)

Comment: I changed the interval to 15 minutes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try addin Log inside the doWork function and see if the log is printed. Also, you may have to wait at least 15 minutes for the work to be triggered.